Module ImportIng Python
E

======================================================================
ERROR: test_search (unittest.loader._FailedTest.test_search)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 419, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 362, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Mes travaux\Python\Pycharm\SeachEverything\tests\test_search.py", line 5, in <module>
    from search.search_by_name import SearchByName
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'search'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
(SeachEverything) PS D:\Mes travaux\Python\Pycharm\SeachEverything> 


import os
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from search.search_by_name import SearchByName


sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'src')))

from src.search.search_by_name import SearchByName
from src.search.files_infos import FileInfos
class TestSearchByName(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.directories = ['/mocked/dir']
    self.filename = 'testfile'
    self.searcher = SearchByName(self.directories, self.filename)

@patch('search_by_name.os.walk')
def test_search_file_found(self, mock_os_walk):
    # Mocking os.walk to simulate the file system
    mock_os_walk.return_value = [
        ('/mocked/dir', ['subdir'], ['testfile.txt', 'otherfile.txt']),
        ('/mocked/dir/subdir', [], ['anotherfile.txt'])
    ]

    # Mocking FileInfos
    with patch('search_by_name.FileInfos') as mock_file_infos:
        mock_instance = mock_file_infos.return_value
        mock_instance.to_dict.return_value = {
            'name': 'testfile.txt',
            'path': '/mocked/dir/testfile.txt',
            'summary': ''
        }
        results = self.searcher.search()

        # Verifying the results
        self.assertEqual(len(results), 1)
        self.assertEqual(results[0]['name'], 'testfile.txt')
        self.assertEqual(results[0]['path'], '/mocked/dir/testfile.txt')


       if __name__ == '__main__':
            unittest.main()

Hi, I'm trying to import files to run my tests, but I'm having issues with the imports and I can't seem to fix them. I've tried various solutions, but none seem to work. The issue is related to a class SearchByName in the search directory.
